# STS assumerole cant call itself

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I tried to run the command `kubectl get svc` and I get into this error

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::0123456789:user/temp is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::0123456789:user/temp
```

The following json is the IAM of user temp

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "eks:DescribeCluster",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:eks:ap-southeast-1:0123456789:cluster/cluster1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: **Side-note:** These permissions allow that IAM User to assume _any role_. This includes any administrative roles that might be in the account. This is a very dangerous level of permissions. I recommend that you limit the roles that can be assumed by this IAM User.

Comment: The error message is saying that the IAM User `temp` is not permitted to AssumeRole on IAM User `temp`. This suggests that instead of trying to assume an IAM Role, the code is trying to assume an IAM User. Check the configurations to see where the Role is meant to be specified, and see whether a User was specified instead.

Comment: now i get this error `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::0123456789:user/temp is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role/eksServiceRole`

Comment: Users are not meant to assume Service Roles. You should be providing an IAM Role that you want software within the pod (?) to use to access AWS services. This is different to the Service Role, which is used by EKS itself to create resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen if your `.kube/config` looks like:

```
- name: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:111122223333:cluster/integ
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-west-2
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - integ
      - --role
      - arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/temp
      command: aws
```

The key part here is the `--role ...user/temp` part.  Which tells the `aws eks get-token` command to first assumeRole before it tries to get the token.

So if your AWS client / setup has already assumed the role in question, it will then try to assume the role *again* when trying to get the EKS login token.  So unless you've added permission for the role to assume itself (which would be silly, but helps workaround this particular issue) then you will see the error.

The fix is to either not assume the role first in your client, or to take the `--role .../temp` out of your `.kube/config`.